# Issue with NULL not allowing a calculation to happen

Tags: sql

I have such a situation I use this command to basically allow division by 0. So far it was working just fine, but now it for some reason no longer works well for me.

```
SET ARITHABORT OFF 
SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF
```

Comment: The root issue is allowing your columns to be *nullable* in the first place. For example, a *quantity* should never be *unknown* ie null, a quantity is always a value, probably zero would be the default. Allowing a column to be nullable must carry some meaning, otherwise you end up with issues such as this.

Comment: What values are "sk.OH" and "sc.QTY"? Also, are you familiar with COALESCE? Would that work here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will depend on what behavior you want to happen when one of the values is null.

If you want to treat it as 0 ( or some other value )

```
ISNULL(sk.OH, 0) + ISNULL(sc.QTY, 0) AS 'Projected Available Inventory (In DC)'
```

If you want to return NULL - or some default value.

```
CASE 
  WHEN sk.oh IS NULL or sc.QTY IS NULL THEN NULL 
  ELSE sk.oh + sc.qty 
  END AS 'Projected Available Inventory (In DC)'
```